# MS Access 2013 form to display "Record is locked for editing by another user" and by whom

Tags: ms-access-2013

When a user tries to edit a record in a MS Access 2013 database form that is currently being edited by another user, is it possible to build a form that would pop-up to display:

1. "This record is locked for editing by another user"
2. The users' name, eg. "John Smith"

The **Record Locks** in the **Property Sheet** of the form is set to **Edited Record** which prevents a second user from editing the same record. However it would be beneficial if the second user could know that the record is locked for editing and the name of the user that is currently editing the record.

I can build the pop-up form however I would require the vba code to detect that a user is in the record and the vba code to display the user's name on the pop-up form.

Thank you,

Al

Answer (score 0):

You could try trapping the specific error so that you can control/customize the message shown to the user. The below code will capture error 3218 and display a message box with custom message to the user. You'll want to wrap your existing VBA commands in this error handler to trap errors. If you're using a bound form that throws an error when a user navigates to a locked record, you could make a macro that also identifies errors and runs this bit of code as well.

```
On Error GoTo err1:

    '*CODE THAT MIGHT THROW ERROR GOES HERE*

err1:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3218
            If MsgBox("Cannot edit - record is locked by another user.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "System Error") = vbOK Then: Exit Sub
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
```

Microsoft has a [long list of trappable errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb221208(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) - so you might want to find the ones specific to your issue and update the CASE statement with each error number.

Identifying the specific user who locked the records is a bit more involved and will take a lot of custom code. [This site](http://etutorials.org/Microsoft+Products/access/Chapter+10.+Multiuser+Applications/Recipe+10.9+Determine+if+a+Record+Is+Locked+and+by+Whom/) has a solution that might fit your needs.

Comment: Great solution DenimChicken!

Comment: Trapping the error with the code will work for part of my issue however I tried the second link regarding identifying the specific user and the Access module in the example database referred to in the post is unavailable (This site). Would you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found the [link](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9780596000844/tree/master/CDROM/chap10) to the Access database 10-09.mdb referred to in the website [This site](http://etutorials.org/Microsoft+Products/access/Chapter+10.+Multiuser+Applications/Recipe+10.9+Determine+if+a+Record+Is+Locked+and+by+Whom/) mentioned below.